# .NetCore 2 Angular 5 - Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BASE_URL]:

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I get this error when i am trying to navigate to a WebApi Controller. This error is what i get as soon as the page loads because the codes are situated in the constructor function.

```
core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BASE_URL]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BASE_URL]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BASE_URL!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BASE_URL]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BASE_URL]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BASE_URL!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:979)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9217)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9911)
    at resolveDep (core.js:10276)
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:979)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9217)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9911)
    at resolveDep (core.js:10276)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Candidates } from '/Solutions/Angular/ExamBuddy/Interfaces/Candidate';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})


export class LoginComponent  {
  candDetails: Candidates;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    var url = baseUrl + '/api/Candidate/ExamDetails/12345';
    this.http.get<Candidates>(url).subscribe(result => { this.candDetails = result; }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

This is also my app.module.ts code.

app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ExamComponent } from './exam/exam.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
    // import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { InstructionComponent } from './instruction/instruction.component';
    import { routes } from './app.route';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ExamComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        InstructionComponent,

      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        routes 
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

i also have the WebApi controller which connects to the database and fetches the result in JSON format.

Comment: what does `BASE_URL` stands for ? Does it have an `@Injectable` decorator ?

Comment: I do not think so. i only imported "inject" from angular/core. My intention is to get the baseurl e.g http://localhost:8080/"api address". what do i do please?

Comment: Those are supposed to be environment variables. Put them into your `environment.ts` files and import this file instead. That's its sole purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. which and which should be in the environmental variables?? Thanks

Comment: Basically everything that depends on your environment. Your API url does. For instance, Firebase config can be part of it, you could even have styles that depend on your environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are injecting a string value with the key `BASE_URL` in your `LoginComponent`, with the inject decorator:  `@Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string`. For this to work you need to provide a value for `BASE_URL` in your AppModule. But you didn't provide a vaule, this is what the error is telling you: `NullInjectorError: No provider for BASE_URL!`

In Angular 5 it is recommended to create `InjectionToken` e.g.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('BASE_URL');
```

providing the value in your AppModule is done by defining a provider in your `AppModule`:

```
providers: [  { provide: BASE_URL , useValue: "http://example.com/api" }
```

you can then use this InjectionToken in your LoginComponent like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(BASE_URL) baseUrl: string) {
```

Further informations regarding injection of values can be found in the offical documentation: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens

Answer (score 4):

**First**: In **main.ts**, I have the following code, which refers to  index.html

```
export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Second**: In our component (**fetch-data.component.ts**), we use the **BASE_URL** in the following way:

```
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

    constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
           this.forecasts = result;
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to enable Hot Module Replacement.  The official instructions for HMR have this example for `main.ts`:

```
Update src/main.ts to use the file we just created:

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { hmrBootstrap } from './hmr';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if (environment.hmr) {
  if (module[ 'hot' ]) {
    hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
  } else {
    console.error('HMR is not enabled for webpack-dev-server!');
    console.log('Are you using the --hmr flag for ng serve?');
  }
} else {
  bootstrap().catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

*(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-configure-hmr)*

However, the Visual Studio 2017 ASP.Net Core Angular CLI template includes these lines:

```
const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Notice that the `providers` array is not being passed into the HMR `main.ts` example. The simple fix is to simply pass it in to `platformBrowserDynamic`. The corrected line then looks like this:

```
const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```